# Separate threshold for each column

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to draw separate "Threshold" line for each column in "Column chart"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [`Renderer.path`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) to render that lines.

To find place where render them, use `point.plotX` and `point.plotY`.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this as a stacked column.

If you want a specific line between the top and bottom, you can use a method to extend the Highcharts maker function to draw a horizontal line as a marker, and use a scatter series to place the lines.

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.hline = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + height / 2,'L',x+width,y + width / 2];
};
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nksudgsp/

If you don't need an explicit line drawn (since the different colors already create that line), just skip the scatter part and use a regular stacked column.

If you want to keep just a single legend item for the whole thing, you can use a dummy series, and the `linkedTo` property.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nksudgsp/2/